# Spring boot WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8081/getUsersList/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-webflux

My below client is throwing the below exception.

I have tried `localhost` as well.

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8081/getUsersList/' failed:
>   Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

When I try hitting the browser, its streaming the data as expected, but when I try to get it from Javascript client its causing the issue.

`http://127.0.0.1:8081/getUsersList`

```
data:19:20:33
data:

data:19:20:34
data:

data:19:20:36
data:

data:19:20:37
```

I think am missing something as part of port mapping, so if some one could help on this would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance!

**Code:**

> index.html - Client

```
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         function WebSocketTest() {

            if ("WebSocket" in window) {
               alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");

               // Let us open a web socket
               var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8081/getUsersList/");

               ws.onopen = function() {

                  // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                  //ws.send("Message to send");
                //  alert("Message is sent...");
               };

               ws.onmessage = function (evt) { 
                  var received_msg = evt.data;
                  alert("Message is received...");
               };

               ws.onclose = function() { 

                  // websocket is closed.
                  alert("Connection is closed..."); 
               };
            } else {

               // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
               alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
        }
      </script>

   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "sse">
         <a href = "javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

> pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Webflux-POC</groupId>
    <artifactId>Webflux-POC</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Webflux-POC</name>
    <description>POC on webflux</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.54</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.websocket/javax.websocket-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

> WebfluxApp.java

```
package com.poc.webflux;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebFlux
@ComponentScan
public class WebfluxApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebfluxApp.class);
    }
}
```

> UsersController.java

```
package com.poc.webflux;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.poc.webflux.service.UserService;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(value="/getUsersList",produces = "text/event-stream")
    public Flux<String> getUsersList(){
        return userService.getUsersList();
    }

}
```

> UserService.java

```
package com.poc.webflux.service;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@Service
public class UserService {

    public Flux<String> getUsersList() {
        return Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate(() -> {
             String str = getRandomNumber();
             System.out.println(str);
             return str ;
        }))
                //.log()
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

    }

    private String getRandomString() {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make a websocket connection at an http endpoint. To expose a websocket connection endpoint on the reactive stack, you need to implement a WebSocketHandler and provide an HandlerMapping to the endpoint and the implemented WebSocketHandler.

In resume:
1 - Create a class that implementes WebSocketHandler and make your business logic on the handle method implemented (in your case the logic of userservice).
2 - Create a @Configuration that exposes a bean of HandlerMapping containing the endpoint you want to make websocket connections and your WebSocketHandler implementation.

See the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-websocket) for further details on reactive websocket implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look, I was new to websocket, so you mean to say that we should not have `@RestController` , instead we should have `Handler` in place of Controllers?